# Why might my SQL query take much longer when I wrap it in a function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that I want to make into a T-SQL function. The query returns data very quickly (<1 sec), but as soon as I wrap it in a function, it takes almost a minute to return the same data:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(NUM_UNITS)
FROM
    VW_ITEMS
WHERE 
    ITEM_ID = 1234
    AND VENDOR = '101'
    AND [TYPE_ID] IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY
    SIGN;
```

...but this function, with the same basic logic inside, takes almost a full minute to return the same results, any ideas why?

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GET_SUM_UNIT_DEALS_V2] 
    (@p_vendor VARCHAR(50),
     @p_item_id INT)
RETURNS NUMERIC(20,5)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @p_vendor IS NOT NULL
        RETURN
            (SELECT SUM(NUM_UNITS)
             FROM VW_ITEMS
             WHERE 
                 ITEM_ID = @p_item_id
                 AND VENDOR = @p_vendor
                 AND [TYPE_ID] IN (1, 2, 3)
             GROUP BY SIGN);
    ELSE
        RETURN
            (SELECT SUM(NUM_UNITS)
             FROM VW_ITEMS
             WHERE 
                 ITEM_ID = @p_item_id
                 AND VENDOR IS NULL
                 AND [TYPE_ID] IN (1, 2, 3)
             GROUP BY SIGN);
    END

    --default case
    RETURN NULL
END
```

Comment: Because multi-line user defined functions are known to perform poorly. If you used an **inline** table value function you will find better performance.

Comment: Quite a bit to unpack there and many possible reasons - depending on if you mean it's poor when used as part of a query or poor when executing stand-alone? First issue could be Parameter Sniffing. Consider breaking the two queries into two separate functions and use this as a "wrapper" to call each - does that improve things...? Alternatively just merge the logic and have a single query ie `where... and (VENDOR = @p_vendor or @p_vendor is null)` and implement as an inline-TVF.

Comment: Please share query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan, and please show table and index definitions. The question is not really answerable otherwise.

Comment: Inline TVF example here https://dbfiddle.uk/yLTwLfZg

Comment: From a performance perspective there are so many things in such little code that are potential problems. I would start with the definition of your views. Are those nested views? If so, that is strike 1. You have strike 2 because you have created your function with multiple execution paths so that any given execution plan stored in the cache is likely going to be less efficient when going down the other path. Strike 3 is using a scalar function, they are notoriously horrible for performance. Keep in mind that your query and your function do very different things because of the multiple paths.

Comment: Among other things they're different code. The first code block uses literals so Query Planner can optimize for those specific values. When it comes to the UDF versions Query Planner may optimize for the first set of supplied scalar values (and cache and reuse that plan for others, no matter how good/bad a plan it was), or it may optimize generically based on index statistics and cardinality.

Comment: The poor performance of user-defined functions (UDFs) is a known issue. They cause the plan to go single-threaded when it could have been parallel across available CPU cores, they use and cause inaccurate cardinality estimates, and they often result in row-by-agonizing-row (RBAR) evaluations - and that's just in the `SELECT`, in the `WHERE` they also break the ability to use indexes (SARGability)